# Snakes and Ladders - Coding the Jump in the Snakes and Ladders

Tags: matlab

I want to make a simple 'Snakes and Ladders' game to go through the motions, so that if I land on a Ladder, which would be represented as an array 
`Ladder = [3 5 11 20];`, then I'd want my `Position` to increase by `LadderGain = [18 3 15 9];` and vise-versa for `Snakes`.

My thought was

```
if Position == Ladder
Position = Position + LadderGain;
end
```

thinking that the index at which it landed would carry over to `LadderGain`. This didn't work. I'm wondering how I can make this operation work without excessive if-statements.

```
   if Ladder(Ladder == Position) 
       Position = Position + LadderGain(find(Ladder == Position,1));
   end
```

This is the solution I've come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it this way:

```
Ladder = [3 5 11 20];       % Ladder positions.
LadderGain = [18 3 15 9];   % Ladder gains.

while true % Loop.
    Position = input('Enter position: ');       % Request user input.

    if any(Position == Ladder)                  % Check if Position matches any of the Ladder positions.
        idx = find(Position == Ladder);         % Find the index of the matching case.
        Position = Position + LadderGain(idx);  % Add the corresponding gain to the position.
    end

    fprintf('Position: %d\n', Position);    % Display new position.
end
```

Test case 1: Player doesn't land on a ladder.

```
Enter position: 0
Position: 0
```

Test case 2: Player lands on a ladder.

```
Enter position: 3
Position: 21
```